# String.Format wrong format error

Tags: vb.net, string.format

I'm stuck on something simple that I can't figure out why doesn't work now.
I tested the same code before(last Friday) and it works

I just need to get an String with four hexadecimal digits from an integer variable no mather what number between &H0000 and &HFFFF

So I write this simple code

```
Dim NumHex As Integer = 352
Dim NumHexStr As String = String.Format("{X4:0}", NumHex)
```

But now I'm getting 
"*Input string was not in a correct format.*"

Can you see something wrong on that code?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you want `{0:X4}`.

Comment: Or `NumHex.ToString("X4")` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format condition must be `String.Format("{0:X4}", value)` or `Value.ToString("X4")` or may be `Hex(value).PadLeft(4, "0"c)`